# For loop only loops once

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a very weird error occurring in my Batch script where a `For` loop is only looping once when it should loop many more times (at least 10 times).

**Can you tell me why my `For` loop is only looping once and how I can fix it?**

```
@ECHO off
CLS
SETLOCAL 

SET macroFolder=_PLACE_4DM_FILES_HERE

REM the following for loop only loops once when it should be looping more 
REM because theres over 10 *.4dm files in the folder??
for /r ./%macroFolder% %%i in ("*.4dm") do SET "file=%%i" (
    echo %file%
    REM Note I need to store %%i in a variable so I can edit it later
    REM And placing %%i in a variable within the for loop results in 
    REM the var being empty for some reason. For eg
    SET file=%%i
    ECHO file is %file%
    REM Prints "file is "
)

ECHO.
PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: try this: `for /r "./%macroFolder%" %%i in ("*.4dm") do echo(%%i`

Comment: Maybe remove the quotes around `*.4dm`?

Comment: You must note that `./%macroFolder%` form is _exactly the same_ than just `%macroFolder%`, that is, %macroFolder% folder in current directory, and usually never used!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have (at least) two problems. The first is that you seem to be mixing the bracketed and non-bracketed form of the `for` statement:

```
for /r ./%macroFolder% %%i in ("*.4dm") do SET "file=%%i" (
    blah blah
)
```

In that case, the non-bracketed bit is executed per-loop-iteration but the bracketed bit executes *after* loop exit. You can see this with:

```
for /r ./%macroFolder% %%i in ("*.4dm") do echo 1 (
    echo 2
)
```

which outputs (in my case where there are three `4dm` files):

```
1 (
1 (
1 (
2
```

Your second problem is that `%%` variable expansion is done before the command executed and the `for` command is a multi-line one, from the `for` to the closing `)` bracket. Any variables you need expanded, that have been set *within* the loop, need to be done with delayed expansion.

Start with this:

```
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@ECHO off
CLS

SET macroFolder=4dmfiles

for /r ./%macroFolder% %%i in ("*.4dm") do (
    SET file=%%i
    ECHO file is !file!
)

ECHO.
PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
```

and you'll see (for my three files):

```
file is C:\Users\Pax\Documents\4dmfiles\1.4dm
file is C:\Users\Pax\Documents\4dmfiles\2.4dm
file is C:\Users\Pax\Documents\4dmfiles\3.4dm
```

Comment: +1 Good explanation! I had never seen the form `for /r ./%macroFolder% %%i in ("*.4dm") do SET "file=%%i" ( blah blah )` before!